# testing a combo box has a selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Just doing the code behind for my combobox, im testing that there is a selection and not what is displayed in the text property (xaml below '-select-'). (also is -select- at index 0?)

*Basically need help structuring the code behind method , if statement.*

if there is selection then adds course to List. Else, it will display messagebox error.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CboxCourseList" Text="-Select-" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

**code behind:**

```
private void AddRequest_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(CboxCourseList) <--**this is where i need help, what property do i need**
              ....
        else{
            MessageBox.Show("Course must be selected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: CboxCourseList.Items.Contains("-Select-") and no, setting the text property does not add anything to the combo box which means it's not at any index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int index;
index=CboxCourseList.SelectedIndex;

if( index!=-1 )
{
     //do stuff
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Course must be selected");
}
```